# Is that possible to use google cardboard API to create native Android application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

We are thinking to port our Android 3D games to support google cardboard VR.
Our games are native android apps and are based on NativeActivity.
The CardboardActivity is a java activity so that can not be used in native app.
I opened the Cardboard library (.arr) and saw some native libraries, but there is no any docs or guideline about how to make native android app with cardboard API. 
Anyone could provide some info or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: you can use Java activities in Native apps.You need to use JNI http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 1):

Your current best bet it to use a CardboardView, and call your native renderer via JNI in CardboardView.Renderer's onDrawFrame() method.
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/CardboardView.Renderer

That would probably require some refactoring of your app, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It means that developers who wants to use CardboardView can not create "pure native" android app with glue lib, which is the case of our Android native app. It has big overhaul in our architecture though. Really hope Cardboard team can open this opportunity to NDK developers.